# Codeigniter Ignited Table combine 2 query field result in one column

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatable

I use Ignited Table and I would like to combine 2 filed results in one column.

```
$this->datatables
            ->select('ci_orders.id,'
                    .'ci_orders.transaction_id,'
                    .'ci_orders.field1,'
                    .'ci_orders.field2,'
                    .'ci_orders.status')
            ->from('ci_orders')
            ->join('ci_users', 'ci_orders.user = ci_users.id')
            ->where('ci_users.id',$userId)
            ->unset_column('ci_orders.id')
            ->add_column('edit', '<a href="' . base_url() . 'cancel_order/$1"><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> Cancel</button>', 'id');
```

with this query I would have a table like

```
---transaction_id---|---field_header1---|---field_header2---|---status---
   some id          |   value1          |   value2          | pending
```

What I would like to achieve

```
---transaction_id---|---field_header---|---status---
   some id          |   value1/value2  | pending
```

is ignited table ablle to handle this?

Comment: You know you don't have to use the AR lib that comes with CI, right? You could just write your own SQL if you want to do something complicated. Also, where are unset_column and add_column defined? Those don't exist in the documentation for the Database class, they're part of the DBForge lib (add_column at least)

Comment: unset_column is a method of Datatable Library https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables/

Comment: That would be important information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While viewing the code at [*Ignited-Datatables / application / libraries / Datatables.php*](https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables/blob/master/application/libraries/Datatables.php) i found the select function of ignited tables it actually used codeigniter's active library so you can use the mysql's [*CONCAT(str1,str2,...)*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function

```
/* demo code just to show ,taken from ignited tables*/
public function select($columns, $backtick_protect = TRUE)
{
  foreach($this->explode(',', $columns) as $val)
  {
    $column = trim(preg_replace('/(.*)\s+as\s+(\w*)/i', '$2', $val));
    $this->columns[] =  $column;
    $this->select[$column] =  trim(preg_replace('/(.*)\s+as\s+(\w*)/i', '$1', $val));
  }

  $this->ci->db->select($columns, $backtick_protect);
  return $this;
}
```

you can try this one by adding second parameter `$backtick_protect` as FALSE

```
$this->datatables
     ->select("ci_orders.id,ci_orders.transaction_id,
     CONCAT(ci_orders.field1, '  ', ci_orders.field2) AS ci_orders.field1,
     ci_orders.status",FALSE)
     ->from('ci_orders')
     ->join('ci_users', 'ci_orders.user = ci_users.id')
     ->where('ci_users.id',$userId)
     ->unset_column('ci_orders.id')
     ->add_column('edit', '<a href="' . base_url() . 'cancel_order/$1"><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> Cancel</button>', 'id');
```